# Logstash tomcat stack trace parsing failed

Tags: tomcat, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, syslog-ng

I'm trying to parse some Tomcat logs with logstash, here is an example of data :

```
 07-05-19 11:24:32 INFO  [XmlWebApplicationContext] Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Apr 10 15:58:07 CEST 2019]; root of context hierarchy" >> /var/lib/docker/volumes/test1/_data/tomcat.misc.log
 09-05-19 10:25:00 WARN  [BasicResourcePool] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@74f26dc -- Acquisition Attempt Failedclear! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to ii refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:265)
            at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner .run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Network is unreachable (connect failed)
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:144)
            ... 13 more
```

I have seen on others topics that multilines plugin and patterns are usefull :

Pattern file :

```
JAVA_TRACE (^.+Exception: .+)|(^\s+at .+)|(^\s+... \d+ more)|(^\s*Caused by:.+)
```

Logstash config file :

```
input {
        udp{
                port => 12201
        }
        tcp{
                port => 12201
                codec => multiline {
                        patterns_dir => ["/conf/patterns"]
                        pattern => "^%{JAVA_TRACE}"
                        negate => "true"
                        what => "previous"
                }
        }
}

filter{
                grok{
                        patterns_dir => ["/conf/patterns"]
                        match => {message => ["(^%{DATE_EU:date} %{TIME:time} %{LOGLEVEL})"]}
                        tag_on_failure => ["failed"]
                }
}

output{
        elasticsearch{
                hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
                index => "tomcat_misc"
        }
}
```

Just for information, here is my syslog-ng client config :

```
source s_test{
        wildcard-file(
                base-dir("/tmp")
                filename-pattern("*log")
                flags(no-parse)
                );
};

template no_header{
        template("$MSG\n");
        template_escape(no);
};

destination d_siem{
        tcp(X.X.X.X port(12201) template(no_header));
};

log {
        source(s_test);
        destination(d_siem);
};
```

The problem is that when i'm using this config, simple line are well parsed, but stack trace lines return a 'failed' tafg as if they are not interpreted in the multilines codec. For example, the 'at com.[...].run' line is stored as one logs line and not as a part of a multiline logs.

I checked on a regex website that my JAVA_TRACE pattern is correct and match with my stacktraces, so I don't understand why the codec is not working ...does anyone have an idea ?

Thx for your help

Comment: Try with `negate => "false"` in your multiline pattern.

Comment: Finally i fixed my troubles with : pattern => "^%{DATE_EU}" in multiline codec and ["(^%{DATE_EU:date} %{TIME:time} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}|(^%{JAVA_TRACE}"]} in grok :)